# Why do I need to add "require("http")" when I already have express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to follow this tutorial on creating a simple chat application using socket.io. I am at the part of the tutorial where I have to insert all of the code below into a js file and initiate it. I just don't understand why the 2nd of code exist, I heard that express can do a lot more than http. Instead of using the "http.listen" code, can't "app.listen" be used and "app" passed to "io" instead?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need to add “require(”http“)” when I already have express?

You don't have to manually load the http module yourself.  You use express to create an http server for you (it will load the http module for you) and integrate it with socket.io without manually loading the htttp module like this:

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Internally, `app.listen()` loads the http module for you, creates a server and then starts it, returning the `server` object which you can then use with socket.io.

Inside of express, this is the code for `app.listen()`:

```
const http = require('http');

app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, somebody had to load the `http` module.  If you use `app.listen()`, the express will do it for you.

Comment: Hi, just wondering for the native code for app.listen(), why isn't there any parameters when arguments like "3000" and the callback are being passed in?

Comment: @guy1733 - `server.listen.apply(server, arguments)` passes all arguments that were passed to `app.listen()` on to `server.listen()`.  You can read about the `.apply()` method and the `arguments` object to learn about how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Express is a framework that sits on top of the nodejs application and provides a much easier,provided more middleware to handle routes, session and cookies and more efficient way to create server as such

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
```

In this example, for the purpose of creating a socket between different channels, you have to use HTTP to indicate that the socket is used to handle HTTP requests/responses. You simply can't pass an entire express application to io.